# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre una peticion http y query manual a firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Ya he investigado algo al respecto, pero no logro entender que es mejor.
Si hacer todo con el tipico instance (Agregando firebase core, firestore y demas) de firebase como esto:

```
    FutureBuilder(
  future: _initializeFirebase(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Error initializing Firebase');
    } else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
        ConnectionState.done) {
      return LoginForm(focusNode: _uidFocusNode);
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator(
      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
        CustomColors.firebaseOrange,
      ),
    );
  },
```

Y demas operaciones de un crud.

A comparacion de hacer una peticion http get por ejemplo.
Como esto:

```
    Future loadProducts() async {
//_baseUrl tiene la url respectiva de firebase
    final url = Uri.https(_baseUrl, 'products.json');
    final resp = await http.get(url);
    //Convertir en mapa de productos
    final Map<String, dynamic> productsMap = json.decode(resp.body); 

    //Barrer cada llave que venga
    //Key es la llave del valor, en este caso ABC123, value lo que tiene dentro (nom url....)
    productsMap.forEach((key, value){
      //Aqui mediante el metodo "Product.fromMap(value)" crea un objeto tipo Product con sus campos llenos
      final tempProduct = Product.fromMap(value);
      //Agrego a una la lista
      this.products.add(tempProduct);
    });

  }
```

Y usar un modelo de Producto como lo pongo en el ejemplo.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cual es la diferencia?. ¿Que es mejor?. Si es que ambas van a Firebase.
Agradezco sus respuestas. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ante todo conviene saber que Firebase dispone de dos tipos de base de datos: Firestore y Realtime Database.

En el caso de [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/use-rest-api) la documentación es bastante clara:

> Si bien la forma más fácil de usar Firestore es usar una de las
> bibliotecas cliente nativas, hay **algunas situaciones** en las que es
> útil llamar directamente a la API de REST.
>
> La API de REST puede ser útil en los siguientes casos prácticos:
>
> - Para acceder a Firestore desde un entorno con recursos restringidos, como un dispositivo de la Internet de las cosas (IoT),
>   caso en el que no es posible ejecutar una biblioteca cliente completa
> - Para automatizar la administración de la base de datos o recuperar metadatos detallados de la base de datos
>
> Si estás usando un [lenguaje compatible con gRPC](https://grpc.io/about/#osp), te recomendamos
> usar la [API de RPC](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/) en lugar de la de REST.

En el caso de Realtime Database, aunque la documentación no es tan explícita cuando habla de su API REST, sí lo es en la [definición](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database?hl=es) misma de esta base de datos, la cual, como su nombre lo indica, está pensada para **sincronización en tiempo real**:

> Almacena y sincroniza datos con nuestra base de datos NoSQL alojada en
> la nube. Los datos se sincronizan con todos los clientes en tiempo
> real y se mantienen disponibles cuando la app no tiene conexión.
>
> Firebase Realtime Database es una base de datos alojada en la nube.
> Los datos se almacenan en formato JSON y se sincronizan en tiempo real
> con cada cliente conectado. Cuando compilas apps multiplataforma con
> nuestros SDK de plataformas de Apple, Android y JavaScript, todos tus
> clientes comparten una instancia de Realtime Database y reciben
> actualizaciones automáticamente con los datos más recientes.

Lo dicho para Realtime Database en cuanto a la sincronización, vale también para Firestore. Desde el SDK de Firebase esto se haría de forma transparente y sin mayor esfuerzo, en cambio, si quieres hacerlo mediante el servicio REST, tendrás que programar código que solicite los datos constantemente.

En resumen, el servicio REST sólo tiene ventaja de ser usado en situaciones como las expuestas al principio. Así que, allí donde puedas usar el SDK, no lo dudes ni un segundo. Con pocas líneas de código, tu App se benificiará de todas las bondades de Firebase sin necesidad de nada más.